# Global display line numbers mode not working

Tags: emacsclient, emacs-daemon, line-numbers

I can run `(display-line-numbers-mode)` and get line numbers but it doesn't work if I run `(global-display-line-numbers-mode)` (nothing happens). I have traced this to this function:

```
(defun display-line-numbers--turn-on ()
  "Turn on `display-line-numbers-mode'."
  (unless (or (minibufferp)
              ;; taken from linum.el
              (and (daemonp) (null (frame-parameter nil 'client))))
    (display-line-numbers-mode)))
```

Sure enough I am running my emacs in daemon mode (I have no idea why that would prevent me from wanting line numbers?) and the `frame-parameter` call is returning nil. I am connecting with a GUI instance of emacsclient. Any idea what this is trying to do and if it is actually necessary?

Comment: I run emacs in daemon mode and global-line-numbers-mode works as expected. Can you reproduce the problem without your init file? i.e., start with `emacs --daemon -Q`? If not, there's something in your config causing the problem.